# Undefined index html

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm new to html so i'm unsure where im going wrong but i have the following code (i'm creating a form and adding values to the database when the user presses submit).

a checkbox nested in a form -

```
<label for="choice1">Windows 7</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice1"/>
```

and when the user presses 'add button' i'm trying to get the value and store it in a variable but it cannot find 'choice1'.

> $choice1=$_POST['choice1'];

but i get "**Undefined index: choice1**". Why is this?

Comment: Is the form's `method` attribute set to `POST`? Is the "add button" an `<input type="submit"/>`? Show more code.

Comment: Show your entire form html please, including the add button.

Comment: In PHP, try `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_GET); echo "</pre>";` to analyze contents of arrays $_POST and $_GET.

Comment: @jakub: `header('Content-Type: text/plain'); var_dump($GLOBALS);` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkbox is checked, the browser sends its value with other variables.

If it's not checked, it's not sent.

Do this:

```
$choice1 = isset($_POST['choice1']) ? $_POST['choice1'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that can go wrong here:

1. If the form doesn't have the attribute `method` set to `post`, the data is passed in the URL (you can check if that is the case). In that case, the values are in $_GET rather than $_POST.
2. Checkboxes that are not checked don't pass a value. If the checkbox is checked, it passes `on` (or another value, if you override it) but if you don't, you don't get the value, so you cannot read it in PHP. You can check if the value exists using `array_key_exists('choice1', $_POST)`. If it doesn't you know the checkbox isn't checked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your form uses POST (not GET), otherwise `$_POST` will be empty. For example:
   `<form action="foo" method="post">`
2. Do a `print_r($_POST)` to see if there's anything inside `$_POST`.
3. As Matt says in the comments, make sure your have `<input type="submit">` to actually send your form.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this should work:

```
 <FORM action="your next page" method="post">
    .....
    <label for="choice1">Windows 7</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice1"/>
    .....
    <input type="submit"/>

 </FORM>
```

Check if your code is the same...
Otherwhise post more code to give a look at...