# Undefined index upon building html dynamically from PHP

Tags: php, html, apache

So I've searched for about an hour and can't find an answer to why I'm getting an `undefined index` on building my `html` dynamically. My array is `info['']` and when I `var_dump` it, it is holding all the values it needs to. Below is my code:

```
function buildProdDisplay($info){
$pd = "<h2>$info[invName]</h2>";
$pd .= "<h3>$info[invPrice]</h3>";
$pd .= "<figure id='prod-display'>";
$pd .= "<img src='$info[invImage]' alt='Image of $info[invName]' on Acme.com>";
$pd .= "<figcaption>";
$pd .= "$info[invDescription]";
$pd .= "</figcaption>";
$pd .= "</figure>";
$pd .= "<div id='sideProduct'>";
$pd .= "<p>";
$pd .= "$info[invStock]<br>";
$pd .= "$info[invSize]<br>";
$pd .= "$info[invWeight]<br>";
$pd .= "$info[invLocation]<br>";
$pd .= "$info[invVendor]<br>";
$pd .= "$info[invStyle]<br>";
$pd .= "</p>";
$pd .= "</div>";
return $pd;
}
```

All the answers I have read both from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631530/undefined-index) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429820/undefined-index-html) that are from stack overflow and [this one](http://ccm.net/faq/3140-php-notice-undefined-index) that is not from Stack Overflow either weren't helpful for my specific case (where the variable, when dumped, shows it holds the correct values) or just suggested to do this (just adding apostrophes around the array element):
`$pd .= "$info['invDescription']";`
Which when I do that, it catches a fatal error saying `unexpected string`.
What am I doing wrong?

Edited to show `var_dump` of info:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(13) { ["invId"]=> string(2) "13" ["invName"]=> string(3) "TNT" ["invDescription"]=> string(76) "The biggest bang for your buck with our nitro-based TNT. Price is per stick." ["invImage"]=> string(29) "/acme/images/products/tnt.png" ["invThumbnail"]=> string(32) "/acme/images/products/tnt-tn.png" ["invPrice"]=> string(5) "10.00" ["invStock"]=> string(4) "1000" ["invSize"]=> string(2) "25" ["invWeight"]=> string(1) "2" ["invLocation"]=> string(8) "San Jose" ["categoryId"]=> string(1) "2" ["invVendor"]=> string(17) "Nobel Enterprises" ["invStyle"]=> string(7) "Plastic" } }
```

Comment: Show us the var_dump of $info.  If you are doing this in a loop where $info is a different array every time maybe one of them doesn't have all the keys.

Comment: @RyanTuosto edited above

Comment: Your `undefined index` error should have a line number. Also, you can change `$pd .= "$info[invStock]"` to `$pd .= $info['invStock']`. The quotes are unnecessary.

Comment: @noahnu yes, the `undefined index` is for every element in the `$info` array in the above function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$info` has an array inside so you can just add `$info = $info[0];` to the top of your function and keep everything else the same

Or in the outer context only pass in this inner array `buildProdDisplay($info[0]);`

Additionally you might want to add `if (isset($info['some_key']))` checks to conditionally add html only if the key exists.

Comment: That worked, I just added the `$info = $info[0]` as the first line of my function and it displayed everything! Now to style it!

Answer (score 1):

Your $info array contains an array in its first index, so you need to access the its first element (which would be the array with keys invId, invName, etc. i.e what you want) and then access the values you actually want. You would do this in the following way:

```
$pd = "<h2>{$info[0]['invName']}</h2>";
```

And the same way for all the other lines.

Comment: So I did that and the error messages changed from `undefined index` to `Array to string conversion`. But, instead of there being nothing displayed in the body of the document, now where all of the `HTML` elements would be it says:<br>`Array[specificinvhere]`